# Посчитать количество символов в определенном количестве строк

Tags: c++, строки, файлы, функции

```
void read(string path) {
    int offset = 0;
    int n = 0;
    char buffer[1];
    ifstream in(path, ios_base::ate);
    if (in.is_open()) {
        while (n < 6) {
            in.seekg(-2, ios_base::cur);
            in.getline(buffer, 1);
            if (buffer[0] == '\n') {
                n++;
            }
            offset++;
        }
        in.seekg(-offset, ios_base::end);
        getline(in, date, '\n');
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            in >> arr_readings[i];
        }
    } else {
        cout << "Ошибка открытия файла для чтения!\n";
    }
    in.close();
}
```

Написал функцию для программы. Она должна открыть файл (в котором только цифры и точки, многострочный) для чтения по пути path, установить курсор в конец файла. Затем подсчитать количество символов в n последних строках и записать это количество в offset. 
Затем перевести курсор с отступом -offset из конца файла, считать первую строку в строчную переменную date, остальные 5 строк (в каждой строке число с плавающей точкой) занести в float массив arr_readings.
Возникла проблема в цикле подсчета символом в 6 строках. Не могу понять, что не так. Буду благодарен подсказке.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (n < 6) {
    in.seekg(-1, ios_base::cur);
    if (in.peek() == '\n') {
        n++;
    }
    offset++;
}
```

Изменил цикл таким образом и все заработало. Использовал peek() для внесения следующего символа в потоке в буфер памяти. Далее проверяется является ли он символом переноса строки, если да - плюсуется счетчик n.